# include_once multiple files from array

Tags: php, function, plugins

Well, I am working on a plugin system.

There is one file `plugin_introduction.php` that is checking, that the INI variable "plugins" is "true", if so, it continues the code and includes a new file `plugins/plugins.php`.

The code of the `plugins/plugins.php`-file:

```
<?php

$dir = dirname(__FILE__) . "/";

$plugin = [
   "testmod" => "$dir" . "testmod/index.php"
];

?>
```

So, now a few informations are stored. The name of the test mod and the location.

But now I want them to be included once into the main file.
Since I don't know how many plugins the users will have, I can't write a few "include_once '...'" statements.

So I thought a function could solve that. The problem is, I don't know how to do that, because I think writing like

```
include_once "$plugin['testmod']";
```

would only work for one plugin.

So how could I solve this problem to load multiple plugins or should it be better, that the user include_once them himself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you include them all by a simple foreach loop?

```php
$plugins = [
   "testmod1" => "$dir" . "testmod1/index.php"
   "testmod2" => "$dir" . "testmod2/index.php"
   "testmod3" => "$dir" . "testmod3/index.php"
];

foreach($plugins as $name => $plugin) {
    include_once $plugin;
}
```

Comment: Sometimes the answer is so simple. Thank you, mate!

Comment: Additionally I recommend to check if file_exists() before include to not break the script.